# Etherchannel connections between Cisco and Nortel switches

Tags: cisco, etherchannel

I need to create a 6 port static Etherchannel link between a stack of 3 Cisco 3850's and a Nortel 8310.  Can someone provided a basic config for the Nortel side.  I have little experience with the platform and online documentation has been frustratingly sparse.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this link and scroll about half way down.

http://forums.networkinfrastructure.info/nortel-ethernet-switching/ers-8300-and-lacp-with-hp-blade-servers/

UPDATE: Fixed - Here's how you get LACP to work with the 8300.

The configuration is simple, for a base line.

Configure your ports and vlans as you would normally (for multiple vlans enable tagging on the port level)

```
config ethernet 1/1-1/2,2/1-2/2 perform-tagging enable
config ethernet 1/1-1/2,2/1-2/2 lacp key 10
config ethernet 1/1-1/2,2/1-2/2 lacp aggregate true
config ehternet 1/1-1/2,2/1-2/2 lacp enable

config vlan 2 create byport 1
config vlan 2 ports add 1/1-1/2,2/1-2/2 member portmember

Configure your mlt group

config mlt 5 create
config mlt 5 lacp key 10
config mlt 5 lacp enable
```